# TEdit Interposer Class Property in VCL

Tags: delphi, vcl

my "useless" Interposer class for TEdit :

```
  TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
    private
      FCheckValid : boolean;
      procedure GetLength;
    published
      property CheckValid : boolean read FCheckValid write FCheckValid;
  end;
```

and it's only procedure :

```
procedure TEdit.GetLength;
var
  aTask : ITask;
begin
  if Length(Self.Text) = 0 then
  begin


    aTask := TTask.Create(
      procedure
      begin
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
          procedure
          begin
            Self.Color:=clYellow;
          end);

        Sleep(100);

        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
          procedure
          begin
            Self.Color:=clWhite;
          end);
      end
    );
    aTask.Start;

  end;
end;
```

Just for the sake of having fun . Is it somehow possible at all to make the VCL show the Property **CheckValid** for newly dropped TEdit Controls on the Form?

Thank you

Comment: You mean that you want to show the property in the Object Inspector? If so, you need to create a true (non-interposer) descendant component and register it.

Comment: On a side note: `Length(Self.Text)` can be changed to `Self.GetTextLen()`. Also, your `TTask` is unnecessary, you can use `TThread.ForceQueue()` without having to start a worker thread at all: `procedure TEdit.GetLength; begin if Self.GetTextLen = 0 then begin TThread.ForceQueue(nil, procedure begin Self.Color := clYellow; TThread.ForceQueue(nil, procedure begin Self.Color := clWhite; end, 100); end); end;` Or alternatively, you can use an internal `TTimer` if your version of Delphi doesn't support the version of `TThread.ForceQueue()` with the `ADelay` parameter.

Comment: Much appreciated ! Thank you Remy!!!